# r not completing execution of function and no error message

Tags: r

I am trying to do a convolution using bayesmeta package in r. I believe that I have correctly called the function (convolve function) but when I run it in the console it does not complete executing and I must manually stop the computation. Any assistance? Here is an MWE:

```
library(bayesmeta)
x <- c(1565,1394,292,10031,1392,18528,930,38941)

d1 <- function(x) {
     return(dexp(x, rate = 0.0001094796))
    }

d1_convolution <- convolve (d1, d1, 
    cdf1 = Vectorize(function(x){integrate(d1, 0, x)$value}),
    cdf2 = Vectorize(function(x){integrate(d1, 0, x)$value}),
    delta = 0.01, epsilon = 0.0001)

d1_convolution
```

Thanks.

Comment: How long have you left it before manually stopping?

Comment: It may take a long time to complete all the calculation, do you have access to a HPC cluster ?

Comment: @GregorThomas the maximum time I left it for computation is 30 minutes